# \pagebreak vs \newpage

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-breaking

What's the difference? I know that `\pagebreak` can take an optional argument that specifies how much a page break is desired, but is there any difference if the optional argument is not used?

Comment: See also the duplicate question [What is the difference between “Page Break” and “New Page”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/what-is-the-difference-between-page-break-and-new-page) for potential additional answers.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Both commands start a new page.

If the optional argument is not used, `\pagebreak` will start a new page and the paragraphs of the old page will be spread out so that the old page will not look like the end of a chapter.

With `\newpage`, on the other hand, the old page will have the blank space at the bottom, because the paragraphs will stick together as if the chapter had ended there.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20100622022829/http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-pagebreaks.shtml) link will be useful, and the [answer to a duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/what-is-the-difference-between-page-break-and-new-page/9855#9855) (that was migrated from SO to this site later) gives the following example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that SO question in my Googling, but I did…

Comment: @Ben: even if you had seen it, it is useful to have the answer here as well!

Comment: @Juan: thanks... I wish I could take more of the credit, but the real work was done by the person who answer the SO question linked above  :)

Comment: and you have the same difference between \newline and \linebreak on the line scale.

Comment: Basically the same spacing differences exist for `\linebreak` vs. `\newline`.

Comment: The "This" link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 24):

`\pagebreak` tries to make the page the same height as other pages if it's possible (by stretching intervals between paragraphs etc) and `\newpage` just fills the page with empty space.

Answer (score 19):

`\newpage` forces a new page at the point at which it occurs.

`\pagebreak` without options forces a new page at the end of the line in which it occurs.

Comment: References: [LaTeX/Command Glossary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Command_Glossary) and [LaTeX/Page Layout: Manual page formatting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Manual_page_formatting)

Answer (score 5):

If you really want the page to be changed, one of the most useful way I found so far is :

```
\clearpage
\pagebreak
```

Answer (score 0):

The `multicols` environment has `\columnbreak`, but it seems to behave more like `\newpage` than `\pagebreak`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).