# What is the difference between "Page Break" and "New Page"?

Tags: page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage)

In LyX/LaTeX,
What is the difference between "Page Break" and "New Page"?

They both seem to do the same to me.

Comment: Should this be marked as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage or the other way round (the accepted answer of the other question references this question)?

Comment: @Caramdir: I guess the accepted answer in that other question has to be updated anyway since it talks about an SO question, which is no longer true. My personal view is somehow that after an appropriate update of the other question, this one could be the duplicate.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

If you use `\newpage`, the page will be directly "cut off" and a new one will begin. The text/paragraphs on the page will not be affected in any way. If you do this, you might have a lot of empty space on that page.

With `\pagebreak`, the paragraphs on the cut page will spread out over the page, so you will not have empty space at the bottom. The old page will not look like it is the end of a chapter.

Here is an example of the results of a `\pagebreak` and a `\newpage` (the pictures show the page on which the command was written. The commands are written at the end of each page to start a new one.):

[image]

Comment: On XeLaTeX both yield the same result for me, like \newpage in this answer. I'm continuing with multicols*{2} though.

Comment: For me with `pdflatex` for a small paragraph they are also the same.

Answer (score 39):

They are similar, though they have a difference:

```
\newpage
```

Forces the current page to end and starts a new one. This will pad the page with extra space at the end of the page.

```
\pagebreak [number]
```

Breaks the current page at the point it is located. Using the optional number argument changes this from a demand to a request with priority in a scale from 0 (low priority) to 4 (high priority). This will not put extra space at the bottom of the page.

See https://web.archive.org/web/20131716503200/http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-pagebreaks.shtml for info on page breaking commands.

Comment: References: [LaTeX/Command Glossary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Command_Glossary) and [LaTeX/Page Layout: Manual page formatting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Manual_page_formatting).