# Why is \pagebreak not working as intended?

Tags: page-breaking

According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/what-is-the-difference-between-page-break-and-new-page/9855#9855), `\pagebreak` will end the current page and the paragraphs on the cut page will spread out over the page. However, when I tried this functionality, it does not seem to be working, am I missing something? The following is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
  paragraph 1

  paragraph 2

  paragraph 3
\pagebreak 

  paragraph 4
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `\flushbottom` in the preamble (or switch to `\documentclass[twoside]{article}`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `article` class sets `\raggedbottom` (unless it is loaded with either the `twoside` or the `twocolumn` option). If you add `\flushbottom` before `\begin{document}` you get the spreading (and an “Underfull `\vbox`” warning).

[image]