# Why there is this space in my text?

Tags: spacing

I know it's all greek to you.But don't mind the language.I wanna know why there is this space between the text of the chapter?
In other chapters there is no such a problem.

[image: Overleaf editor]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../PICS/}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[figurename=εικόνα]{caption}


\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
% Redefine plain style, which is used for titlepage and chapter beginnings
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30230/828
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\rhead{\thechapter }
\lhead{ \chaptername}
\rfoot{\thepage}
%\graphicspath{{../PICS/}}



\def\tl{\textlatin}
\def\tg{\textgreek}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{sloppypar} % δεν εχουμε προβλημα με το overfull hbox
\include{cover}
\title{Μελέτη, ανάπτυξη και ενσωμάτωση ψηφιακού φωνητικού βοηθού στο έξυπνο σπίτι με χρήση opensource τεχνολογιών}
\author{ΧΑΤΖΟΓΛΟΥ ΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΣ \\
\date{Μάρτιος 2022}}
%\today\\
%\href{mailto:ece00559@uowm.gr}{\tl{ece00559@uowm.gr}}}
\maketitle
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Κατάλογος Εικόνων}%αλλαγη του table of figures(καταλογος σχηματων) 
{\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Κατάλογος Εικόνων}


\part {Ανάλυση}
\include{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\part{Υλοποίηση}
\include{DOCUMENT/hardware}
\include {DOCUMENT/Install}
\include{DOCUMENT/software} 
\part{Συμπεράσμα και Μελλοντικές Επεκτάσεις}
\include{DOCUMENT/expansions}
\appendix
\include{acronyms}


\selectlanguage{greek}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}

\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's really much easier for us to diagnose if you put the code into your question; it's not easy to read a screen shot.  Also, it's helpful to know the document class and relevant packages that you're using.  But here I will make a guess -- you have a figure and ask for it `[H]`.  The figure doesn't fit, and goes to the next page.  This looks like a book class, and books typically have flush bottoms.  So the text of that section is shoved down to the bottom, leaving a space above it.  Try changing `[H]` to `[ht]` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. As @barbarabeeton pointed out, without seeing the full code (ideally as plain text, not screenshots) it's very difficult to diagnose the problem. Also making the code minimal is helpful, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/11002 for guiadance. Still I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: you are using `[H]` which is an explicit request to get bad space, or rather to stop latex avoiding bad space, so you need to adjust the text by hand. latex floats figures to stop getting bad space forced by page breaks, so naturally if you use `[H]` which just disables the floating mechanism, then you get bad spaces unless you position the figures "by hand", to enable page breaking  in better places.

Comment: @kostas When you add sample code to your question you should use the code formatting option, to do so select the code and then click the button with the curly braces at the top of the editor.

Comment: Not really a clear example, as your contents are missing, but it reminds me of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/what-is-the-difference-between-page-break-and-new-page/9855#9855).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `PICS/rhasspyservices.PNG` is too big.  TeX would like to move the "Web Server" subsection up onto the page and put the picture after that subsection, but your `[H]` doesn't allow that.  There's nothing else to put on the page, so TeX spaces out the paragraphs so that there isn't a big blank area at the bottom of your page.

[Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/107497) will have some helpful information.