# Setting the text of a small chapter more compact

Tags: page-breaking

Is there any way to force latex to put text on the same page, but not spreading it over more than one page?

I have a chapter which is about 1 1/4 pages long. Latex sets it very sparsly. I would appreciate it if latex sets the text more compact.

I have tried to put a pagebreak right after the paragraph of the next page, to instrument latex where to put the pagebreak. Instead of omitting the pagebreak suggested by latex, two pagebreaks are made and the text still spreads very sparsely over the first page.

[image: wrong pagebreak]

using `\newpage` the document looks either like

[image: wrong pagebreak]

or

[image: wrong pagebreak]

using no pagepreak or newline at all the chapter looks like

[image: wrong pagebreak]

Comment: Does this question help: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage)

Comment: no unfortunately not, with newpage it looks like: http://imgur.com/5xoae.png and http://i.imgur.com/6LQ1M.png

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (i.e. a code example that compiles and shows the problem).

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been a figure at the end of the chapter before the current one. By adding the parameter [h] to this figure the problem disappeared!