# Bad looking table of contents (on entire page)

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, page-breaking

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\frenchspacing
\linespread{1.3}
\author{Me}
\title{My title}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
    \pagebreak

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section Blah}
Blah blah blah
\section{Section Xaxa}
Xaxa xaxa xaxa
\end{document}
```

That is my doc. When I use documentclass `mwrep` I got table of contents that is on entire page (even if there are 2 sections in one chapter). But when I use `article`, table of contents looks fine. How can I get `article`'s look in `mwrep`?

EDIT:
You are right that chapter won't work with article. What I mean is that I want ToC to look like in article. It would be better to ask how can I get `report`'s look in `mwrep`.

'mwrep' is supposed to be report class adjusted to Polish typography. How did I get it? I just typed `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}` and LEd downloaded it.

**EDIT 2:**
Look at the difference between mwrep and report here: http://min.us/mdHsA6D and here: http://min.us/mdHsA6D#2

Comment: (Note: Your example won't work with the `article` class because you're using the `\chapter` command.) Do you want to remove the page break between the table of contents and chapter 1? I wouldn't recommend this, because the ToC should be typeset as an unnumbered chapter.

Comment: Where did you find the `mwrep` you are using?

Comment: @N.N.: It is included in the `mwcls` package which is part of TeX Live.

Comment: Add the following to your preamble: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}`. The ToC should now be formatted as an unnumbered section. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @lockstep: No, now it looks like it this pdf http://min.us/mW1st9 . I want it to look like in http://min.us/mdHsA6D#2 , except I want dot after chapter number (in ToC) like in http://min.us/mdHsA6D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove `\pagebreak`. See [\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage) for details.

EDIT: To clarify: `\chapter` internally uses at least one `\clearpage`, which (for one-column mode) essentially is `\newpage` plus typesetting left-over floats.

Comment: `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak`. So simple... so obvious :D. Thanx :)