# everything is bold, and pagebreaks are appearing in the wrong place

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs

I'm just starting trying to use texmaker 3.3.2. I think I understand the basics but already in a very short document, I have multiple problems. I just downloaded texmaker so I don't think I accidentally changed any defaults or settings.

First problem: All the text is bold unless there is other formatting that overrides it, e.g. an enumerated list or table of contents.

Second: All of the pagebreaks appear one paragraph before I inserted them.

I'm using the default settings of PdfLaTeX + View PDF but I tried some of the others, and it still happens. At first I thought my text might have a sequence of characters causing the bold, but it clearly doesn't, since I replaced it with the dummy text below and it's still happening.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Me}
\title{My title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\paragraph{I would like to thank my research advisor.}
\paragraph{And some other people. }
\paragraph{This always ends up AFTER the page break, alas.}
\pagebreak
\section*{Abstract}
\paragraph{Most of the abstract.}
\paragraph{One more thing that also appears after a pagebreak.}
\pagebreak
\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I posted this before getting very far into it; it won't take me too long to clean up my excess zeal with the macros.

Comment: My comment did not get carried over in the migration, so in case there is any confusion the above is a response to:  
The bold text goes away if you simply don't use the \paragraph{} macro. Just leave a blank line between paragraphs. BTW, LaTeX related questions are better posted at TeX.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\paragraph` is not intended for setting normal text, it is a heading, on the level below `subsubsection`. See any introductory text, such as [the wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_Commands) or [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort).

Just write normal text directly, and separate paragraphs with an empty line. Also, `\newpage` is usually better than `\pagebreak` (see comment by egreg). See [\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage) for the difference between them.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Me}
\title{My title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section*{Acknowledgements}
I would like to thank my research advisor.

And some other people. 

This always ends up AFTER the page break, alas.
\newpage
\section*{Abstract}
Most of the abstract.

One more thing that also appears after a pagebreak.
\newpage
\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd only use `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak` which is useful for fine tuning the typesetting.

Comment: @egreg I'm wasn't really aware of the differences between them, I just  copied the OPs MWE and fixed the `paragraph`s. I'll update my answer.

Comment: In the case of `oneside` documents, which use `\raggedbottom`, the difference is not apparent, but try with a `twoside` document and you'll see it: `\pagebreak` flushes the page to the bottom margin, while `\newpage` doesn't.