# Difference between \newpage and \vfill\eject

Tags: page-breaking

I think I understand the difference between [`newpage` and `pagebreak`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage).

My question mostly comes out os curiosity. I came across this way to get a new page: `\vfill\eject`. What is the difference between this and just `\newpage` (or `\pagebreak`). Does it have an advantage?

Comment: `\vfill` and `\eject` are tex primitives.  they are used to define the latex commands `\newpage` and `\pagebreak`, but the latter contain additional checks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton are you sure `\eject` is primitive:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- ya got me.  `\eject` is defined in `plain.tex` as `{\par\penalty-10000 }` (texbook version).  it *is* "pre-latex", however.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a big difference between `\newpage` and `\vfill\eject`.

- Definition of `\newpage` in LaTeX

  ```
  % latex.ltx, line 6342:
  \def \newpage {%
    \if@noskipsec
      \ifx \@nodocument\relax
        \leavevmode
        \global \@noskipsecfalse
      \fi
    \fi
    \if@inlabel
      \leavevmode
      \global \@inlabelfalse
    \fi
    \if@nobreak \@nobreakfalse \everypar{}\fi
    \par
    \vfil
    \penalty -\@M}
  ```
- Definition of `\eject` in Plain TeX

  ```
  % plain.tex, line 558:
  \def\break{\penalty-\@M}

  % plain.tex, line 564:
  \def\eject{\par\break}
  ```

LaTeX tries first to catch problems with `\everypar`; if `\newpage` is given in  sectional titles or immediately after or else in lists, some countermeasures are taken.

After this the working is *almost* identical, but you can notice that `\newpage` issues `\vfil`, because of how it deals with `\flushbottom` and `\raggedbottom`. Both constructions end with `\penalty-10000` that forces a page break.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Would you be able to express this in more layman's terms?

Comment: @Thomas What's before `\par` in the definition of `\newpage` is somewhat technical; LaTeX, in some circumstances, sets some parameters in a way that's not appropriate for normal text and in those cases simply issue the penalty for forcing the page break would give wrong results.

Comment: Does the term `\eject` has any roots in typography?

Comment: @Viesturs I don't think so. The idea is that the completed page box is pushed out of TeX's memory.