# classicthesis: second page of toc has different spacing

Tags: classicthesis, scrbook

[image: faulty table of contents]
Hi,

from the attached toc you can probably already see what is wrong with my table of contents.
The first page is perfect but somehow I get strange spacing on the second page.

And also, it would be nice if the heading for chapter 4 would be on the second page instead of the first one.

I think this has to do with the combination of classicthesis and scrbook but I am not 100% sure.
Do you know what the error might be?
I have been googleing it for quite a while with no success.

Thank you,

Roman

And here is also the code to produce the result:

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdfspacing, linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel, style=english]{csquotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage[
  style=numeric,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{sections/titlepage}
\pagebreak
\input{sections/abstract}
\input{sections/declaration}
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\mainmatter
\input{sections/introduction}
\input{sections/stateoftheart}
\input{sections/methods}
\input{sections/results}
\input{sections/conclusion}

\printbibliography
\newpage
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: remove `\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\tableofcontents`

Comment: see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue, but it clearly depends on your wrong usage of `\newpage` and `\pagebreak`.

There's no need, in general, to issue such commands: a `\chapter` command (which is implicit in `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures`) will by itself issue a safe page break command. Note also that `\pagebreak` will try to stretch the page so the text preciding `\pagebreak` sits at the bottom of the page, which is what you see.

There's no need to issue `\pagenumbering` either, because this is already taken care of by `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.

Here's a version that fixes the described glitches.

```
\documentclass[dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdfspacing, linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel, style=english]{csquotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\usepackage{tocloft} % not needed, already loaded by classicthesis

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example


\usepackage[
  style=numeric,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
A title
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Abstract}
Whatever

\chapter{Declaration}
Something

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

% emulate some chapters
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\printbibliography

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]