# moderncv: pagebreak does not adjust the text to the page

Tags: page-breaking, moderncv

I am using moderncv to write my resume. I have one job position entry which is split between two pages. I tried to use `\pagebreak`, although it did move the entry to the next page, the previous text was not adjusted with the extra space. [Unlike described in this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage)

Example code:

```
\cventry{DATE}{Position}{Company}{Location}{}{}
\cvlistitem{Role 1}
\cvlistitem{Role 2}
\cvlistitem{Role 3}
\cvlistitem{Role 4}
```

It overflows into the new page after `Role 2`.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to reproduce your problem (you should have given a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), I start with:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\moderncvtheme[green]{casual}
\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
\section{Something or other}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
%
\section{Positions}
\cventry{DATE}{Position}{Company}{Location}{}{}
\cvlistitem{Role 1}
\cvlistitem{Role 2}
\cvlistitem{Role 3}
\cvlistitem{Role 4}
%
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: split-role]

Adding a `\pagebreak` before the positions' section gives:

[image: break-unbalanced]

Indeed the first page is ragged at the bottom.  The reason is that the `moderncv` class chooses not to introduce vertical stretching lengths, neither between paragraphs (implicitly introduced by the `\lipsum` command here) nor at section headers and list items.  Of course, you can introduce them yourself wherever you like:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\moderncvtheme[green]{casual}
\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
\section{Something or other}
\lipsum[1]\vfill
\lipsum[2]\vfill
\lipsum[3]\vfill
%
\pagebreak
%
\section{Positions}
\cventry{DATE}{Position}{Company}{Location}{}{}
\cvlistitem{Role 1}
\cvlistitem{Role 2}
\cvlistitem{Role 3}
\cvlistitem{Role 4}
%
\end{document}
```

and then you get something closer to what you want:

[image: break-vfill]

To do this automatically (i.e., to properly introduce stretching lengths between paragraphs, list items, section headers, etc.), I'm afraid you need to tweak the `moderncv` class quite a lot.  Unless I'm missing something, it was clearly the author's intention to leave the pages ragged at the bottom.  I suggest that you leave it like this, or you choose a different CV class that better suits your taste.

Comment: Plus, the `moderncv` class sets `\raggedbottom` by default.