# Why doesn't pagebreak remove extra space at the bottom of the page?

Tags: lyx, page-breaking

After reading about the differences between \pagebreak and \newpage I have noticed that the \pagebreak doesn't work as it is supposed to. Why is that? Am I missing something? Is there something I should add to the preamble?

This happens with both \pagebreak{} and with \pagebreak[4]

Code:

```
%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
asdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf
g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh
adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf
afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd
fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag
ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdg

asdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf
g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh
adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf
afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd
fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag
ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdg

asdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf
g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh
adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf
afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd
fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag
ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdg

asdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf
g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh
adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf
afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd
fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag
ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdg

asdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf
g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh
adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf
afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd
fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag
ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdg

\pagebreak[4]

asdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf
g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh
adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf
afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd
fdh gjhsfdgag ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdgasdgf g dfh adfgsdaf afgsd fdh gjhsfdgag
ag gfd gsg sdhgfsdg
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: @Sigur something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/740/90948), stretched text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must enable `\flushbottom`. The default in article is `\raggedbottom`.

[image]

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Add the command to the preamble.

Comment: @Jon Although the mystery is solved (+1) instead of manual `\pagebreaks` maybe you want really a shrinkable and stretchable `\parskip`? The `parskip` package could be even a better option in more complex documents.