# Use itemize in combination with koma-moderncvclassic

Tags: itemize, komacv

Why does latex throw an error, when using the `itemize` environment.

I would like to use `itemize` in a `\cventry` of the `koma-moderncvclassic` package, but latex throws the error:

```
Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{itemize}
```

Here, a minimal example to retrace the situation:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% cv title
\renewcommand*{\title}{Curriculum Vitae}
\newcommand*{\firstname}{Max}
\newcommand*{\familyname}{Muster}
\newcommand*{\acadtitle}{* tt.mm.yyyy}
% load cv package
\usepackage{koma-moderncvclassic}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\newpage

\section{Experience}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description.\newline{}%
    Detailed achievements:%
    \begin{itemize}%
        \item Achievement 1;
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

Without the `\newpage` or `\maketitle` command, the error vanishes. Does anybody have a good idea to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. If `\newpage` is replaced by `\pagebreak` the error vanishes.

For the difference of these commands see Post [\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage/).