# Simulating "\cventry" of moderncv without this class

Tags: moderncv, cv

Is there a way to get the `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}` effect in plain LaTeX without the use of the `moderncv` package?

Is there a `\newcommand` patch for `\cventry` which when initialized in any standard TeX file will reproduce this effect of `moderncv`?

Comment: Do you only need `\cventry`? What is with the `\section` command etc.?

Comment: \section will work even under normal class. So I am not too worried about that.

Comment: It will work in other classes but with an different layout: the leading colored rule is then missing ... Do you really want that? Can you explain better what you want to do with that new command? Can you please add an short compilable tex code what you have tried so far?

Comment: I need to copy my CV into a different file which has a completely different document class. There is no simple way to import it unless I can recreate the \cventry in that new file.

Comment: In package `koma-moderncvclassic` (search for it on CTAN) that is already done. For a simple example please have a look to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466746/16550

Comment: So if this package is called then "\cventry" of moderncv class will work?

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Did you saw that command `\section` is changed too? Why do you not simply use `pdfpages` to include your cv into the other document?

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: Thanks for asking! So it seems that doing \usepackage{koma-moderncvclassic} is not only making the CV section of the file compile like "moderncvclassic" but it is also affecting the \section, \subsection, \chapter title looks and fonts everywhere else! This is clearly not the wanted scenrio - I need the \cventry to work only in the CV section of the file.

Comment: Please see my added answer! If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do this by your own with a little bit try and error like this:

1. Copy the definition of command `\cventry` into your other class in the preamble and use command `\cventry` in the document.
2. Compile and see the resulting error: `command \cvitem is undefined`.
3. Copy the definition of command `\cvitem` into the preamble. Do not forget to add the needed packages (`calc`, `xcolor` and `ifthen`) ...
4. Compile and see the resulting errors: some more definitions are missing.
5. Copy the missing definitions into the preamble and compile again.
6. If you got all missing definitions the code can compile now.

Please see the following example for class `article` and command `\cventry`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}   % <=================================================
\usepackage{xcolor} % <=================================================
\usepackage{ifthen} % <=================================================

% <================== added code from moderncv.cls and moderncvbodyi.sty
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}

\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}

\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\textwidth-\leftskip-\rightskip-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,100} % <================================== blue
\newcommand*{\hintfont}{\mdseries} % <================================== bold
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is a usual paragraph in the document. This is a usual paragraph in the document. 
This is a usual paragraph in the document. This is a usual paragraph in the document. 
This is a usual paragraph in the document. This is a usual paragraph in the document. 

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{really very long Institution--3}{very long City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}%
  {This is a very long description--6. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description. 
   This is a very long description. This is a very long description}  

\end{document}
```

and see its resulting pdf page:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Let me try and get back to you!

Comment: @gradstudent do you have any news for us?