# Table of contents starting in the middle of the page

Tags: texlive, thesis, update

I'm writing my dissertation and everything worked fine until I upgraded to texlive 2019. Now my table of contents suddenly starts in the middle of the page. It worked fine before, please help!

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

abcd

\chapter{title}
\section{title}

abcd

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `\pagebreak` but `\newpage` (see also [\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage))

Comment: @siracusa That solves the problem, but why was it working with previous texlive?

Comment: If you didn't change your document, I can only guess that the output slightly changed due to package updates, giving a big enough change to trigger the dramatic `\pagebreak` effect.

Comment: I did not change the document, only updated and after the update it did not work

Comment: I think I remember a change in latex which could explain this, but \pagebreak is simply wrong so it doesn't make much sense to search for the details.