# A better \pagebreak making the old page text reach the bottompage

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs

I read in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage) tread `\pagebreak` allow breaking page in a pretty way so the old page doesn’t look like an end of chapter.

By the way, `\pagebreak` still let some space between the last text line and the bottom page, as you can see with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}




\paragraph{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin, massa id pretium gravida, sapien velit tempus quam, quis molestie arcu nunc sit amet eros. Suspendisse potenti. Proin lacinia ullamcorper erat, vitae finibus lectus suscipit ac. Nam efficitur ultricies velit sed consectetur. Phasellus facilisis nisl justo, id tempor nulla pulvinar id. Mauris finibus nunc dui, eget lobortis est convallis ac. Vestibulum id augue ac elit viverra pulvinar.

\paragraph{}
Quisque id pharetra leo. Nam fringilla neque non purus lobortis, mattis pulvinar justo convallis. Maecenas ex est, vestibulum ut metus ut, euismod interdum leo. Aliquam eu condimentum quam, eu elementum quam. Fusce vestibulum enim eu enim sollicitudin accumsan. Donec molestie fermentum commodo. Vestibulum ultrices elit turpis, vel bibendum dolor vehicula vitae. Donec tempus elit pharetra velit feugiat varius. Sed porta augue nunc. In consectetur accumsan felis, non sodales massa.

\paragraph{}
Donec nec faucibus nibh. Integer id dignissim ante, ac eleifend elit. Aliquam quis urna neque. Cras ullamcorper enim quis elit aliquet eleifend. Sed dictum ac nisl euismod lacinia. Praesent scelerisque quis metus et malesuada. Duis varius diam tincidunt tempor facilisis.

\paragraph{}
In feugiat risus sed nisl feugiat, imperdiet blandit arcu lacinia. Nam laoreet leo pharetra lorem tristique, ut accumsan neque commodo. Etiam sit amet dui quis erat facilisis tempus. Nulla dui ligula, ultricies quis ante mattis, imperdiet rutrum orci. Curabitur nisi ante, egestas eget lacus sit amet, molestie ultrices ex. Ut odio dui, pellentesque eu ex pellentesque, dignissim convallis nunc. Cras gravida, libero sit amet dictum facilisis, elit turpis scelerisque magna, eget mollis ante justo vel justo. In sit amet elementum nibh, at suscipit urna. Mauris maximus neque in faucibus gravida.

\paragraph{}
Morbi dictum, velit a luctus mattis, quam sapien fringilla elit, sed eleifend massa ante quis ante. Sed vel augue ultrices, ornare urna quis, rhoncus ligula. Maecenas ligula sem, convallis eget elit ut, faucibus luctus ligula. Praesent non sagittis sem, eu interdum elit. Nulla ut turpis lorem. Nam accumsan, nisl vitae rutrum tempus, odio nibh vulputate lacus, vitae posuere metus dolor at lorem. Duis congue aliquam eros, ut fermentum mauris hendrerit hendrerit.
\verb|\pagebreak|\pagebreak

\paragraph{}
Nulla tincidunt vel ex a lobortis. Ut dictum neque auctor, commodo nisi venenatis, pulvinar lorem. Proin ullamcorper pharetra mauris nec dignissim. Pellentesque massa elit, ultricies non arcu eu, hendrerit porttitor sapien. In eu fermentum risus. Fusce posuere enim a tristique ultrices. Nulla ante erat, venenatis non arcu in, efficitur placerat nibh. Sed mattis vel nibh et porttitor. Vestibulum blandit risus ipsum, quis vestibulum nulla hendrerit at.

\end{document}
```

With the associated rendering:

[image: Rendering of the MWE]

So, is their a way to force the text to be stretched until it reach the bottom page?

Comment: you need to set `\flushbottom` if you want the page to stretch.

Comment: It work :) If you make an answer I can mark it as solution.

Comment: Note adding fushbottom produces `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active ` ie it produces a document warning about the worst possible output badness. If you do not add stretchy space at the bottom, you should add it within the page (changing the space for `\paragraph` for example) or re-write the text to fit the page

Comment: What if the text on the last page is only a couple of lines long?